# What is the Japanese phrase to convey the meaning of "to declare attendance"?

Tags: word-choice

We as employees of a relatively big company are often prompted to log on to and log out from by wiping our fingers on a bio-metric scanner, for example, to declare our attendance.

Shortly speaking, what is the Japanese word or phrase to convey the meaning of "to declare attendance"? In other words, what is the word or phrase to fill the following blank space?

> 社員は平日にバイオメトリックスキャナで　＿＿＿＿＿　(し)なくてはならない。
>
> The employees must **declare their attendance** on weekdays using a bio-metric scanner.

## Edit:

Another example,

> 太郎：寝坊してしまいまして、すみません。
>
> Taro: I am sorry for coming late.
>
> 店長：悪いですね。じゃあ、早く ＿＿＿＿　して、このネギを切ってください。
>
> Store manager: It is bad, isn't it? Well, please quickly "declare your attendance" and cut this onion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrases you are looking for would be:

「[出勤]{しゅっきん}・[退勤]{たいきん}の[打刻]{だこく}をする」

「出勤・退勤（の）[時刻]{じこく}を[記録]{きろく}する」

You could use 「[出社]{しゅっしゃ}・[退社]{たいしゃ}」 instead of 「出勤・退勤」 as well.

EDIT: For your second example sentence, you could use:

「出社時刻を打刻して」、「タイムカードを[打]{う}って」(if they use a time card), etc.